# Spring 5 reactive websockets: Clients not receiving same data from hot stream

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have this in my `WebSocketHandler` implementation:

```
@Override
public Mono<Void> handle(WebSocketSession session) {

    return session.send(
       session.receive()
              .flatMap(webSocketMessage -> {
                  int id = Integer.parseInt(webSocketMessage.getPayloadAsText());

                  Flux<EfficiencyData> flux = service.subscribeToEfficiencyData(id);
                  var publisher = flux
                      .<String>handle((o, sink) -> {
                         try {
                            sink.next(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(o));
                         } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();                               
                         }
                      })
                      .map(session::textMessage);

                  return publisher;
              })
    );
}
```

The `Flux<EfficiencyData>` is currently generated for testing in the service as follows:

```
public Flux<EfficiencyData> subscribeToEfficiencyData(long weavingLoomId) {
    return Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
               .map(aLong -> {
                   longAdder.increment();
                   return new EfficiencyData(new MachineSpeed(
                           RotationSpeed.ofRpm(longAdder.intValue()),
                           RotationSpeed.ofRpm(0),
                           RotationSpeed.ofRpm(400)));
               }).publish().autoConnect();
}
```

I am using `publish().autoConnect()` to make it a hot stream. I created a unit test that starts 2 threads that do this on the returned `Flux`:

```
flux.log().handle((s, sink) -> {
            LOGGER.info("{}", s.getMachineSpeed().getCurrent());
        }).subscribe();
```

In this case, I see both threads printing out the same value every second.

However, when I open 2 browser tabs, I don't see the same values in both my web pages. The more websocket clients that connect, the more the values are apart (So each value from the original Flux seems to be sent to a different client, instead of sent to all of them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to fix this thanks to [Brian Clozel on twitter](https://twitter.com/bclozel/status/1103541488984702977).

The issue is that for each connecting websocket client, I call the `service.subscribeToEfficiencyData(id)` method, which returns a *new* Flux every time it is called. So of course, those independent Flux'es are not being shared between the different websocket clients.

To fix the issue, I create the `Flux` instance in the constructor or a `PostConstruct` method of my service so the `subscribeToEfficiencyData` returns the same Flux instance every time.

Note that `.publish().autoConnect()` on the Flux remains important, because without that websocket clients will again see different values!